# number of returns in a function

Tags: python, return

Is there any harm if we use many return positions in a python function ?
Like suppose if I want to return a function if **value is not 3 and value is not None** (Just a scenario). So it can be done in so many ways like

```
def return_value(value):
 if value != 3:
  return None
 if value is not None:
  return None
 if value != 'string':
  return None
```

or It can be done like this:

```
def return_value(value):
 if value != 3 or value is not None or value !='string':
  return None
```

Again, I would like to use second way of writing code only, but just for a doubt I am asking having many returns somehow affects the performance of function or not ?

Comment: No it wouldn't in this case

Comment: that was a just a scenario, Can you explain by giving your scenario if it affects.

Comment: You shouldn't worry, write readable code. Your code will be slow if it is inefficient, not based on how you structure it.

Comment: If the code gets more complicated, the first way will be easier to insert comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no harm in having many `return`s.

That said, I would in this case definitely go with the second version. The first is harder to read, and slower (although optimizing for speed without a benchmark is always premature). It is not the many `return`s that make its lower though, but the many `if`s.

Answer (score 4):

It seems a very interesting scenario that you have used above, but conceptually there is no issue with multiple return points in a function.

In a real scenario, it is likely that your test conditions will be logically similar, and that grouping them together, as in your second example, will make good logical sense and keep your code easy to read.

Cheers